# Does the Newton International Fellowship holder get salary?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, salary

The Newton International Fellowship supports the development and training of postdoctoral researchers at an early stage of their career from any country outside the UK, by providing an opportunity to work at a UK research institution for two years. It provides £30,000 per annum for subsistence costs (as a stipend).

My Question is - can the Newton International Fellowship holder get salary from the host organization?

Comment: Extra pay seems unlikely. Available funds will be put whee the needs are most likely. And funds aren't unlimited.

Comment: Glancing over the documents at their website it is unclear. They do not rule out supplementing, and indeed state various places that the Fellow needs to be treated the same as others in similar position with respect to support and benefits. I think the question needs to be directed to someone at the Royal Society or the prospective host institution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since the Newton Fellowship is paid as a stipend, I think it is tax-exempt. Then 30k should be similar what a postdoc or early career lecturer takes home after tax.

Comment: As @PieterNaaijkens says, £30k after tax equates to ~£40k before tax, which is above the average UK household income and would be seen as a reasonably good salary for an early-career academic outside London.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not the Royal Society would allow you to receive additional salary on top of the NIF stipend I cannot say with any degree of certainty. However, regardless I don't think there is any reason why such extra salary would be offered.

The NIF is paid as a stipend, which usually means that it is tax exempt (you should confirm this with your host/the Royal Society).  £30,000 per annum tax free already puts you in the high range for postdoc salaries in the UK (which start at about £30,000 per annum before tax). As such it is hard to argue you should be paid more.

One possible exception is if your position is in London, where salaries are typically a bit higher to compensate for the high cost of living.

Comment: This reasoning sounds plausible, but this is just not how universities act in practice. The university may supplement the stipend if they get sufficiently much out of it so that the deal is worth it for them. If the university gets significantly more money from the Royal Society than they pass on to the fellow, then the fellow has grounds for negotiation, otherwise probably not so much.